# How to get List<T> from Razor Page using typescript?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, typescript, razor

I have ViewModel and Items collection within:

```
public class ItemViewModel{
   public List<Item> Items {get;set;}
}
```

On my `Index.cshtml` i have:

```
@if(Model.Items != null){
     <li><a id="item-id-link" href="#" data-items="@Model.Items"> ...
}
```

Trying to get data using typescript:

```
function getData(context: Jquery){
....
     context.find("item-id-link").click(e => {
          const items = #(e.target).data('data-items');
     });
}
```

As result within items i have list of item datatype not a list of items:

```
"System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ItemViewModel]"
```

I've tried to enumerate it using `for of` to check elements within this list:

```
for (let item of items) {
     console.log(item);
}
```

but it returns me  each word of `"System.Collections.Generic.List'1[ItemViewModel]"`

I also tired to add `.ToList()` in Razor Page but it didn't help.

Could you please tell me what can i do in this case ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@Model.Items` is collection, you need change to this

```
@if(Model.Items != null){
  <li><a id="item-id-link" href="#" data-items="@string.Join(", ", Model.Items.Select(c=>c.Id))"> ...  
   // assume Item class has Id property
}
```